# Hide row in dynamic grid in ZK framework

Tags: zk, zk-grid

I am trying to hide/show a row in a grid (filled dynamically from Java code) upon clicking on it's previous row. To simulate a simple MasterDetail component. I get the right index of the clicked row in the java code, however changing visibility of the row doesn't work! Can anyone help me with this or is there a similar way to to this?

Thanks,
Pooya

Here is the code for the ZUL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <window id="callbackLogWindow"
            apply="CallbackLogWindowComposer"
            border="none" height="100%" width="100%"
            xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client">
        <grid id="callbackLogGrid" oddRowSclass="non-odd" height="100%">
            <columns>
                <column label="Logging Name" />
                <column label="Status" />
                <column label="DateTime" />
                <column label="Subject" />
                <column label="Replies" />
            </columns>
            <rows>
                <zk forEach="${callbackLogWindow$composer.callbacks}">
                    <row sclass='${forEachStatus.index % 2 != 0 ? "z-grid-odd" : ""}'
                    onClick="callbackLogWindow$composer.toggleRow(self.index)">
                        <custom-attributes callback="${each}"/>
                        <cell><label value="${callback.loggingName}" /></cell>
                        <cell><label value="${callback.resolved}" /></cell>
                        <cell><label value="${callback.callbackTime}" /></cell>
                        <cell><label value="${callback.subject}" /></cell>
                        <cell><label value="${callback.resolvedItemCount}" /></cell>
                    </row>
                    <row sclass='${forEachStatus.index % 2 != 0 ? "z-grid-odd" : ""}'>
                        <cell colspan="5">
                            <include src="callbackItem.zul" callback="${each}"/>
                        </cell>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <custom-attributes callback="${each}"/>
                        <button onClick="callbackLogWindow$composer.saveCallbackItems(callback)">
                           Save
                        </button>
                    </row>
                </zk>
            </rows>
        </grid>
    </window>
</zk>
```

And the controller:

```
public class CallbackLogWindowComposer extends SelectorComposer<Window> {

    @Inject private CallbackDao callbackDao;
    @Wire Grid callbackLogGrid;
    private List<Callback> callbacks = new ArrayList<Callback>();

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Window window) throws Exception {

        super.doAfterCompose(window);
    }

    public List<Callback> getCallbacks() {

        callbacks = callbackDao.findAll();
        return callbacks;
    }

    public void toggleRow(int i) {

        Component row = callbackLogGrid.getRows().getChildren().get(i+1);
        row.setVisible(row.isVisible());
        callbackLogGrid.renderAll();
    }

    public void saveCallbackItems(Callback cb) {
        callbackDao.saveInTransaction(cb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure and not test but i can suggest one thing here to you Zk have `visible="true/false"` attribute you can apply this attribute in each row and bind this with your  databean variable For more detail i can suggest let us suppose you have a `List<A> list`
and `list` contain all the record which you want to display now add another variable like `display` in class `A` and control it by your self .And `onClick` on any row change update any other item of list .

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and the solution I found was:

> row visible=""

```
            <grid model="@bind(vm.total)" vflex="1" emptyMessage="No records exist" width="315px" >
            <columns>
                <column width="45%"/>
                <column width="25%" />
            </columns>
            <template name="model">
                <row visible="@load(each.visible)">
                    <checkbox   label="@load(each.label)" style="font-weight:bold" if="${each.checkbox}"/>
                    <label      value="@load(each.label)" style="font-weight:bold" unless="${each.checkbox}"/>
                    <doublebox  value="@bind(each.value)" sclass="textBoxNumber" locale="us" readonly="true" />
                </row>
            </template>  
        </grid>
        </groupbox>
```